# Bubblesort not working for some reason

Tags: c++, algorithm, bubble-sort

I tried to write basic bubblesort in C++, and now I'm stuck. Any ideas why that might not work? I suppose it's obvious for more experienced people, but not for me.

liczba_liczb is number of array cells, niePosort is the array.

```
cout<<"\n\nRozpoczynam sortowanie:";
    for(int i=0;i<liczba_liczb-1;i++){  

        for(int j=0;j<liczba_liczb-1-i;j++){

            if(niePosort[j]>niePosort[j+1]){

                cout<<"\n"<<niePosort[j]<<">"<<niePosort[j+1]<<", zamiana.";

                temp = niePosort[j+1];
                niePosort[j+1]=niePosort[j];
                niePosort[j] = temp;
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Dude! its [working](https://ideone.com/sd9l0n)!!

Comment: Why would you write bubble sort? It is neither efficient nor easy to write; there are lots of algorithms that manage at least one. Try selection sort.

Answer (score 1):

I do not understand what you mean saying that the code does not work. I tried it and it works. I only changed the array name for simplicity.

```
#include <iostream>

int main() 
{
   const size_t N = 10;
   int a[] = { 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0 };

   for ( size_t i = 0; i < N - 1; i++ )
   {  
      for ( size_t j = 0; j < N - 1 - i; j++ )
      {
         if ( a[j] > a[j+1] )
         {
            int temp = a[j+1];
            a[j+1] = a[j];
            a[j] = temp;
         }
      }
   }

   for ( int x : a ) std::cout << x << ' ';
   std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

The output is

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

That is the code sorts the array in the ascending order.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that it was as simple as changing loops conditions to:

`for(int i=0;i<liczba_liczb;i++)`

```
for(int j=0;j<liczba_liczb-1-i;j++)
```

What was suggested by someone who, unfortunately, deleted his comment.

Comment: Can you provide the case for which it was not working? I deleted the answer because I thought it should work even if you have compared one less time. Because if you have sorted n-1 elements and put them at the end then by default the last one will also be sorted.

Comment: @Tahlil - it didn't work for any random numbers form 0 to 200, if there were more than three of them. For three numbers, it was 50-50 chance. The problem with the first loop was it didn't provide all cycles needed for sorting, after making this change there is more cycles and program is working just fine.

Comment: (For 1 based positioning) What bubble sort does is, First iteration: the greatest value is at the `end position` of the array. Second iteration: the second greatest value is in `end position - 1`, Third iteration: the third greatest value is in the `end position -2` and so on. So you see when you have positioned `n-1`th greatest element at `end position - (n-1)`th position which is `2`nd position the array is already sorted. Because you know the first position now contains n the greatest element which is also the smallest one. So your code should work.

Comment: I have tested your code with cases containing more than 9 random elements which it passes. Maybe something else is wrong with your code which you didn't share here. Edit for previous comment : `n-1`th greatest element at `end position - (n-2)`

Comment: You have not tested it when liczba_liczb is not the actual length of the array, bu the largest index into the array..  But its hard to say since those parts of the code are missing, and no test data in and out was shown.

Comment: @Dan what do you mean by largest index? Do you mean `actual length - 1`th index?

Comment: What I mean is the length of an array and the largest index are not equal.  If you carry the largest value to SIZE - 1, then there is never a need to compare that value, at MAX_INDEX ever again.  Whether you have 3 duplicate values or not.  More iterations will not make it a smaller value.  Your last iteration comparing [0]  with [1] would be j=0, j<(1) or j < LENGTH - MAX_INDEX.  So if the equation is j < LENGTH - 1 - I, then I must be ...   MAX_INDEX - 1.  Not LENGTH -1.  So yeah there seems to be some code missing  where liczba_liczb is being set to MAX_INDEX, not LENGTH.